# Is there a term for Chinese-derived "kunyomi"?

Tags: kanji

So, when it comes to kanji readings, there is onyomi and kunyomi, plus some exceptions and in-between cases.  One interesting type of reading that I've come across a few times is when a kanji has a "kunyomi" reading that comes from Chinese.

That is, it's "kunyomi" since the reading is derived from the meaning, not the sound (of the character in Chinese), but rather than using a native Japanese word, it uses *another* Chinese word.

The only example I can think of off the top of my head is a pretty obscure one: the name of the Japanese leek/onion. The original Chinese-derived term is 「辣韮」 (らっきょう).  However, it can be also written 「薤」(a single character that also means leak/onion) while still being pronounced「らっきょう」. I've seen the kunyomi reading of「薤」listed as「らっきょう」in dictionaries.

What are some other examples you can think of?  Is there a particular name for this type of kanji reading?

Comment: Related: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%BE%A9%E8%A8%93